# Как проверить прописан ли у определенного элемента определенное правило css

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сам вопрос прописан в JS 
Не обращайте внимание на разметку, это на скорую руку.
Это я так решил по быстрому реализовать вложенность.

Главным образом меня интересует на чистом JS,  а JQ  если только будет просто дополнением для других читателей.

```js
// так я захватываю все элементы в body
var allBlocks = document.body.querySelectorAll('*');

var wrapperMenu = document.getElementById('wrapperMenu');

// при том, что я набросад разметку я знаю, что есть  такой элем с таким ID
// или в цикле прокрутить если  таких элементов более одного
// и могу получить background-image и  его значение
var allElemBgStyle = getComputedStyle(wrapperMenu)['background-image'];


// а если разметку не я писал, как мне вычислить  вот у этой группы allBlocks
// то бишь, пробежаться по всем узлам   в body
// и проверить  у какого элемента прописано правило
// background-image, что бы создать из них отдельный массив ????

//
```

```css
body * {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 25px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url(https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=91d3138fca6842ef590e56ed2a8dd40d&n=33&h=215&w=344);
  background-size: cover;
}

p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
}

nav:nth-child(2) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: url(http://wallpapers-best.com/uploads/posts/2015-10/10_waterfall.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<main id="wrapper">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <p class="childBlock"></p>
    <p class="childBlock"></p>
    <div class="wrapperMenu" id="wrapperMenu">
      <nav class="menu"></nav>
      <nav class="menu"></nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <p class="childBlock"></p>
    <p class="childBlock"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="parentBlock">
    <p class="childBlock"></p>
    <p class="childBlock"></p>
    <p class="childBlock"></p>
  </div>
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pmMiUFGi_ws/UaL2vAIlsgI/AAAAAAAALYo/0j2tKXyVU-A/s1600/img+(5).jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pmMiUFGi_ws/UaL2vAIlsgI/AAAAAAAALYo/0j2tKXyVU-A/s1600/img+(5).jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pmMiUFGi_ws/UaL2vAIlsgI/AAAAAAAALYo/0j2tKXyVU-A/s1600/img+(5).jpg" alt="">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pmMiUFGi_ws/UaL2vAIlsgI/AAAAAAAALYo/0j2tKXyVU-A/s1600/img+(5).jpg" alt="">
</main>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691258/how-to-query-whole-dom-for-elements-matching-some-computed-style-in-pure-js

Comment: благодарю, пошел разбираться...

Comment: Есть в JS - Element.matches(), который вернет true, если есть стиль. Но он поддерживается не всеми браузерами. IE 11+ Тут есть пример, который аналогичный вашему https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: Igor Lut, ты читал описание? это совсем другое...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const div = document.body.querySelector('div');

  /*  строкой ниже  проверяем есть ли у блока ".bg" правило в стилях background-image   а если нет то вернется none*/
  document.body.querySelector('.info').innerHTML = 
  getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('background-image')
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #242424;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-image: url(http://333v.ru/uploads/00/000a7db0d4c688263a3e8d09e1f5fa93.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #404040;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<main id="wrapper">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="info"></div>

</main>
```